# WordPress Theme customization : remove top header from blu theme

Tags: wordpress, menu, header, themes

I'm working with BLU theme and I want to change the header and the menu appearance, if any one have worked with this theme can tell me how to remove those  sections: 
[image]

Comment: Stack Overflow is typically used by those who have atleast a basic understanding of coding.  The ethos being 'This is what I have done so far but ...' rather than 'This is my problem.  Can someone solve it for me'.  A good starting point, for understanding WordPress and its coding etc, would be https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-files/

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to give exact instructions, without knowing how the Theme has been put together; both structurally and from a coding perspective.

As a broad and general directive, you will need to first create a WordPress [Child Theme](https://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes).  Failure to implement a Child Theme, will result in your desired changes being lost, should you implement an Theme update by the Theme Author.

Once the Child Theme has been created, you will need to find the file responsible for the site's header.  This is typically `header.php` and is found within the following directory:

`wp-content > themes > theme-name`

Once found, you would then need to make a copy of this and place it within the root of your Child Theme.  You can then perform the relevant modifications, to the `header.php` file.

**Issues**

If you are still seeing the Top Bar/Header, then you will need to go through the `header.php` and 'read' the code, to see if said file is calling additional templates, responsible for the Top Bar/Header.  Furthermore, look for other files entitled `header-[some file name].php`.  This is where it will be impossible for someone to give clear instructions, due to not knowing the exact coding used or structural setup implemented.  With knowing such information, it is a fairly simple process.

Have you not thought about asking the Theme Author?

Answer (score 0):

Add this to Additional CSS.

## custom-header {

```
padding: 50px 0;
position: relative;
text-align: center;
z-index: 22;
display: none;
background: #181818;
```

}

Note:  display: none; is the attribute which makes custom Header hide.